# Calculate p-Value of ChiSquare in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker, chi-squared, p-value

Can you help me to find a formula for p-Value of ChiSquare in FileMaker?
I'm not mathematical if someone can explain me step by step what I have to do I'd really appreciate it.

My formula for ChiSquare is:

```
Roudend (

Let ( [

A = E6 ;
B = F6 ;
C = E7;
D = F7 ;

NRAB = Sum ( A ; B) ;
NRCD = Sum ( C ; D) ;
NCAC = Sum ( A ; C ) ;
NCBD = Sum ( B ; D ) ;

N = Sum ( A ; B ; C ; D ) ;

ExA = (NRAB * NCAC) / N ;
ExB = (NRAB * NCBD) / N ;
ExC = (NRCD * NCAC) / N ;
ExD = (NRCD * NCBD) / N ;

CQ = (((A - ExA) ^ 2) / ExA) + (((B - ExB) ^ 2) / ExB) + (((C - ExC) ^ 2) / ExC) + (((D - ExD) ^ 2) / ExD)] ; 
CQ ) ; 3 )
```

where (**E6**,**E7**,**F6**,**F7**) are number of a table 2x2 cell.